# Drupal 7 Elysia Cron "Cron could not run because an invalid key was used" issue

Tags: php, drupal, cron, drupal-7

We are using Elysia Cron for our Drupal websites. We have configured external CRON tab which accesses the CRON URL at https://mysite.mycompany.com/cron.php?cron_key=abcxyz.

But when we checked the logs it is showing error

> "Cron could not run because an invalid key was used".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the cron.php page requires a "cron key" to protect against
unauthorized access. Your site's cron key is automatically generated during
installation and is specific to your site. The full URL of the page, with the
cron key, is available in the "Cron maintenance tasks" section of the Status
report page at Administration > Reports > Status report.

Comment: I am using the cron key from the Cron maintenance tasks section of status report page. But still getting the "invalid cron key" issue.                                                 Actually my site url is like a subdomain url  https://mysite.mycompany.com. Is there any problem with the  URL as it is like a subdoamin url.   Somewhere in the Drupal forums i read that Cron will not run from external url if the site url is subdomain

Comment: NO there are not any issue with sub-domain, you just need to make sure that you copy correct url from admin reports.

Comment: So this error appears even if you copy full path directly from cron maintenance page, past it in browser address bar and call it?

Comment: Rather then copy, just click on the url, if still you face problem, please run update.php and check every thing fine, if not then update the core drupal with latest version.